# Django-Python datetime localization issue

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am getting different results on console and in database. There are UTC differences. I see the correct result on console, however when I save it, I see the wrong timestamp in database.

In console, I am trying the following;

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 27, 12, 57, 16, 376403)
```

Which is corrrect result for me.

In my model.py, I have the following;

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

import pytz

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    last_update_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

I am running `python manage.py makemigrations`and `python manage.py migrate`. After that, I am running my application.

In database, there are 2 hours difference.

what could be the reason for that?

Comment: Your question isn't much clear.Show some code you've tried

Comment: Can you provide an example? Right now it is very hard to see what the problem is. By showing a "*scenario*" with the result, we might be of more help.

Comment: I edited the question and added some sample code from my project. Could you please check it?